# Android ListView image onclick parsing

Tags: android, xml, listview, imageview

My list view is parsed from a online resource, but i cant get the listview to pass the image src to the single list item

SingleMenuItemActivity

```
static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.libraryonclick);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String song = in.getStringExtra(KEY_SONG);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView lblArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Drawable imgThumb = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.onclickthumb)).getDrawable(); //   thumb image
    TextView lblDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Button link3Btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    link3Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
            startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
        }
    });

    lblSong.setText(song);
    lblArtist.setText(artist);
    lblDuration.setText(duration);
    imgThumb.setImageResource(thumb_url);

    //Maybe more code here?
}
```

ListViewActivity

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48258247/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.library);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String song = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
            String thumb_url = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getText().toString();
            String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, org.scouts.library.SingleMenuItem.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_SONG, song);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });     
}
```

i think i need to parse through the imageloader class maybe

Comment: Yes i do want to show the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try this one -

```
URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Create one `ImageView` in your `CustomizedListView` class and `oncreate()` method receive url path from the calling file through intent. And paste it in below code and try it.

And, have a look [this](http://www.ziddu.com/download/19661275/ImgLoadFrmWeb.zip.html) example

Comment: it comes up with add cast to 'imgThumb'

Comment: ur one, but i fixed it i hope :P

Comment: 07-02 20:06:04.519: E/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Is that exception from my sample application?

Comment: I know the exception is coming from `CustomizedListView` java file? am i right? Post full logcat through pastie.org or pastebin.com

Comment: String thumb_url = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getText().toString();]

Comment: tried changing from textview to image but can't without errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13304/discussion-between-spk-and-squiressquire)